# How do I run a CodenameOne program on an iPhone?

Tags: codenameone

I successfully ran the CodenameOne HelloWorld program on the simulator with the IntelliJ IDEA compiler on Windows 10.  How do I run the program on my iPhone SE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to "Send a Build" as is shown (for Android) in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oR3KHYf5OrY&feature=emb_logo (starts at 2:29).

You just right click the project, select "Codename One" and select to send an iOS development build.

But this **won't work**. As explained a bit later in the same video you need one more thing and that's a certificate from Apple. Apple requires that all iOS apps are signed with a valid certificate even if they're running on your own phone. So you must have a valid iOS developer account and you can generate a certificate/provisioning profile for the phone. We have a simplified wizard in Codename One to generate both without requiring a Mac (which is normally a requirement).